# Merge touching polygons with keeping their attributes

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcmap, merge, adjacency

I've got a layer of polygons

[image: Polygons]
Although they all in the same layer, each polygon own some unique data like the date of this polygon and an amount it possess (a number).

I want to join/merge all the adjacent polygons, the end results will be 1 polygon for every stack of polygons, but this 1 polygon will hold the data of all the polygons it holds (and even a count).

Any idea how to do that ? I tried to mess around with the integrate and dissolve, but got mostly non-relevant results.
I'm using both QGIS and ArcMap, so any solution for those programs will be great.

Comment: Since polygons overlap but not exactly there is question of whether to preserve only areas that overlap, or a single, consistent shape for each stack. As MBT86's answer mentions, Union is going to be the quickest way to combine the attributes, but it will create unique shapes based on overlap (so you'll have extraneous polys around a 'core' that has what you want). Something to consider however, is that if you're trying to combine different values for the *same* field in a single record, your goal is going to make a mess of/destroy the attributes. A screenshot of the attribute table may help.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend looking at using your resulting dissolve features from your previous trials with a spatial join ([ArcGIS 10.1 Spatial Join Help Page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s00000032000000)) to attach the original attributes to combined polygons.

Or alternatively look at using union ([ArcGIS 10.1 Union Help Page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000s000000)) followed by dissolving with relevant summary statistics.